# Cache and Session problems in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My Laravel application was previously working great. However, after 10k user registrations on my website in one day and 100k visitors, suddenly the authentication system is failing and every refresh on my website shows you as another authenticated member.

I solved this problem by removing all files in 
/storage/framework/cahch and sessions folder

What is the reason of this problem and how can I solve it?
ps:  using laravel authentication system

**update** 
in laravel log file 
this is the error 
when session failed
[2017-02-27 20:14:12] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with                 message 'fopen(/home/user/public_html/app/storage/framework/sessions/ztTt6PyeLtTPaAd46kY75wn3YZFbS6SZ9td9oDBU): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /home/user/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:54

Comment: Have you updated your Laravel installation in this time? Change Laravel version in same branch for example from 5.3.1 to 5.3.12 or change from 5.2 to 5.3?

Comment: no i didn't make any update , but in my vps they install NGINX in this time, and after uninstall nginx and clear cache and session folder application working again

Answer (score 0):

IMHO an advice: with your number of visitors/users use the Database driver for the Session.
If you have an extensive use of the Cache dont use the file driver for the Cache too, use any other driver: redis, database ecc.

Comment: what the difference between this drivers and can i use database driver after using file driver

Comment: A good database (i.e. Postgresql, mariadb ecc) its better at handling lot of concurrent request. I had problems too with filesystem session driver. You can switch easily you have only to put your app in maintence, make the migration and change the config. Users will be logged of also: old Cache and Session data will be lost.

Comment: iam using mysql , Is no solution with problems in filesystem session drive ??

Comment: imho its a problem of scalability, you have a high concurrent web server (nginx) with a not so concurrent driver. More info here (read the second comment): https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14385

Answer (score 0):

Use database driver for session. File based storage is specific to a server.It is possible that you are using a cloud based server pool like amazon EC2 and the load balancer is selecting a server randomly for every incoming user to balance the load.